# Implement a function like concat in Haskell without using any prelude functions

Tags: haskell

Im trying to implement a function that can flatten a list of lists. only one layer deep. so if I called `flatten [[3],[3, 5]]` I would get [3,3,5]. this is my code:

```
flatten :: [[a]] -> [a]
flatten [[]] = []
flatten [(x:xs)] = 
 flatten [xs] ++ [x]
```

I am getting an error "non exhaustive patterns in function flatten" when I call `flatten [[3], [5]]`

Comment: `(++)` is a prelude function.

Answer (score 9):

There are two fundamental patterns to consider when processing a list. Any list must be either:

- the empty list (`[]`)
- a cons cell (`_:_`)

Since concat acts upon a list-of-lists, we can break that second case down into two cases by pattern matching on the first element of the list, which must be either

- the empty list (`[]:_`)
- a cons cell (`(_:_):_`)<sup>1</sup>

Which gives us three patterns all together:

```
concat [] = ...
concat ([]:xss) = ...
concat ((x:xs):xss) = ...
```

See how *every* list-of-lists **must** match *exactly one* of those patterns?

Now, given that breakdown, see if you can implement `concat` only using `x`, `xs`, `xss`, `:`, `[]`, and `concat` itself.

---

1. *note that `(_:_):_` is a different pattern from `_:_:_`, which is more explictly written `_:(_:_)`. The former is a pattern for a non-empty list at the head of a list of lists. The latter is a pattern for a list of at least two elements.*

Answer (score 3):

Possible solution:

```
flatten [] = []
flatten ([]:vs) = flatten vs
flatten ((x:xs):vs) = x:flatten (xs:vs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using incorrect patterns.
`[smth]` matches list with one element, in your case:

`[[]]` - is list with one empty list
`[(x:xs)]` - is list with one element - list `(x:xs)`, which is not empty

So both cases matches single-element list. That's why function fails on `[[3], [5]]`

Obviously, you may wanted other two cases: empty (`[]`) and not empty list (`(x:xs)`)

```
flatten :: [[a]] -> [a]
flatten [] = []
flatten (x:xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it exactly the same way concat is implemented in [Prelude](https://teaching.csse.uwa.edu.au/units/CITS3211/lectureNotes/tourofprelude.html#concat):

```
flatten :: [[a]] -> [a]
flatten xs = foldr (++) [] xs
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39521946/implement-a-function-like-concat-in-haskell-without-using-any-prelude-functions/70444427#comment66359969_39521946